# Closing a window with close() will close all open windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using Python and I have a main window with a button that opens another window which contain stackedWidget, when the user click "Finish" on the second window I want to close it. but when i try to use self.close() method it closing the main windows as well.

here is the part in my code that handle the Finish click event on the second window:

```
def click_next(self):

        if self.next.text()!="Finish>":
         if self.stackedWidget.currentIndex()!=2:

          self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.stackedWidget.currentIndex()+1)
         else:
            self.next.setText("Finish>")
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.stackedWidget.currentIndex() + 1)
        else:
            self.close()
```

Is there another way to close one window and keep the main open.

Thanks.

---

So for the example I created 2 windows ( main and screen1), the button in main will open screen1 and the button in screen1 expected to close only screen1 but it close both windows.
code for main window:

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from screen1 import Ui_screen1
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(584, 567)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda:

 self.gotoscreen1())
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 260, 131, 51))
        self.button.setObjectName("buton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 584, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def gotoscreen1(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_screen1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "go to screen1"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

code for screen1:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_screen1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(384, 567)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.close())

        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 260, 131, 51))
        self.button.setObjectName("buton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 584, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def close(self):
        self.close()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_screen1()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What class does this inherit from?

Comment: It inherit from MainWindow class of the second window, the code it too,long otherwise i would have paste it here.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. We don't need all the long code, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @NirEyal Other than what correctly pointed out in the answer by Alexander, be aware that you shall never, EVER edit pyuic generated files (as clearly warned in the header comments you ignored and removed). I know that there are tutorials telling that you "can" to do that, but they are just ***WRONG***, as that's a terrible practice that should never be done unless you **really** know what you're doing. The only common, correct and proper way to use pyuic generated files is by following the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Thank you for the note I will follow the link you sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that it is closing both windows, it's that your whole app is crashing because it has reached the `maximum recursion depth`.

The issue is with your `close` method.

```
    def close(self):
        self.close()
```

All this is doing is calling itself over and over and over again until it crashes the program.

To fix this simply remove the close method completely, then in your `setupUi` method change the line that creates the `self.button` to:

```
self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=MainWindow.close)
```

I would also recommend subclassing `QMainWindow` instead of using the uic-like design.